# How would I sort this SP list in an SPFX webpart?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to sort a list that is being received into an SP webpart. I want to sort it by it's ID column.
I'm getting the items from the list using:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Reports").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {

      let returnedItemsFullA: IListAItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new ListAItem(item); });
```

After reading other posts I understand that you have to sort before you map but I don't know how to incorporate the sort with the above.

Regards,
T

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Array.sort** method to sort by Id before calling **map** like this:

```
items.sort((a, b) => a.Id.localeCompare(b.Id)).map((item) => {
  //Rest of the logic on sorted item
});
```

Comment: Would you know how I would incorporate that with the sp.web call above?

Comment: You can push the items to your **returnedItemsFullA** variable like this:

`
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Reports").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
  let returnedItemsFullA: IListAItem[] = [];
  items.sort((a, b) => a.Id.localeCompare(b.Id)).map((item) => {
    returnedItemsFullA.push(item);
  });
});

`

Answer (score 1):

You could use function orderby provided by pnp js.

Sample:

```
let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    web.lists.getByTitle('test3').items.orderBy("ID",true).get().then(response => console.log(response));
```

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/

[image]